# How would I correctly code some audio synths using loops?

Tags: audio, p5.js

This p5.js sketch is not working well: https://codepen.io/truffel/pen/vJYGQv

This one does, and it illustrates my idea of making my code a little better by using loops, but it doesn't have audio: https://codepen.io/truffel/pen/brGpKb

I have coded the same program,by repeating lots of the same lines of code, and manually changing its parameters, but I would like to use loops to make it shorter. The audio worked in my past code (the one that doesn't use loops).

BTW, from my first codepen, would this syntax be ok?

```javascript
for (var k=0; k < envs.length; k++){

envs[i].setEnv();
envs[i].setOsc();

}
```

And this one?

```javascript
for (var j = 0; j < bubbles.length; j++){
             if(i == j && bubbles[i].bounce()){
                            playEnv[i](); }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stack Overflow really isn't designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. It's for specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. That being said, I'll try to help in a general sense.

You should really try to be more specific than saying something doesn't work. The first CodePen you posted contains an error because it has mismatched `{ }` curly brackets. Please try to use proper indentation, so it's easier to spot errors like this.

And just taking a quick glance at your code, I noticed this:

```
for (var k=0; k < envs.length; k++){
  envs[i].setEnv();
  envs[i].setOsc();
}
```

Here, you're using `k` as a loop variable, but you're using `i`. What do you expect this code to do? Have you tried debugging this to see exactly what's going on?

Please try to start smaller, and work in much smaller chunks. You can't write code by copy-pasting a bunch of code and hoping for it to work. You have to [break your problem down into smaller steps](http://HappyCoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and then take on those steps one at a time. For example: can you create a basic sketch that plays a single note? Work your way up from there instead of trying to make everything work at once. Good luck.